# Why does this not work? Python webscraping

Tags: python, html, css, web, beautifulsoup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6py7g.png)I use this code to get all the text within the li tags back, but it doesn't work.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page = requests.get("https://archief.amsterdam/inventarissen/scans/31245/120.3")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
result = soup.find_all('#modal > div > div.content > div > div > ul > li:nth-child(1) > span.file-name')

for i in range(len(result)):
    print(result[i].text.strip())

print(len(result))
```

[image of the website where i want data from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeuAA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the site is creating those tags using JavaScript, and the requests module doesn't run JS at all, so the tags never appear in `page.content`.

You could use something like [requests-html](https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/) or [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) to allow for the JS to run before you access the content, or scrape the data the page loads directly (I checked, and there's a request made to the server that returns the data you need in JSON format. Check the Network tab of your browser's Developer Tools while loading the page for more info/if you want to use that).

Also,

- You could simplify your selector to `li span.file-name`, assuming you want to get every filename.
- Python supports for-loops like this: `for result in results`, so you could use that instead of the more traditional/JavaScript-y variety. I'll put an example below.

```py
# This is assuming the "result" variable is renamed to "results".
for result in results:
    print(result.text.strip())

print(len(results))
```

---

**Data Scraping Method (response to comment)**

1. Replace the webpage's URL in your call to `requests.get` with the API's.
2. Convert the [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) text returned by the server to regular JSON, so that we can parse it using Python's standard `json` library.
3. Iterate through the parsed JSON, pulling out the value of "name"  and adding it to some list.

Full example:

```py
import json
import requests

# The URL from the network tab.
api_url = "https://webservices.picturae.com/archives/scans/31245/120.3?apiKey=eb37e65a-eb47-11e9-b95c-60f81db16c0e&lang=nl_NL&findingAid=31245&path=120.3&callback=callback_json5"
response = requests.get(api_url)
# The split() and strip() calls here remove parts of the request
# that are JSONP, not JSON. We need just the JSON data.
raw_json = response.text.split("(", 1)[1].strip(")")
# Load the JSON data into a regular Python dictionary.
data = json.loads(raw_json)
# Add all the filenames from the data into the filenames list.
filenames = []
for scan in data["scans"]["scans"]:
    filename = scan["name"]
    print(filename)
    filenames.append(filename)

print("\nFilename count:", len(filenames))
```

Comment: thanks for the tips, I looked in the network tab and indeed it contains what I actually need. do you know how i can retrieve this with python

Comment: I have added an image for the explanation

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6py7g.png

Comment: @FezTalmest I've updated my answer with an explanation of how to do that and an example. Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you very much, it worked!